# Managing dynamic lists with jQuery Mobile and Phonegap

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a list to display from a database. Each item in the list is associated with an ID. I want to know the best way to keep track of the ID of each item in the list. So when I click on the item, I can use the ID to map to other attributes of the item in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the "best way", but one way you can do this is through embedding the id in the anchor tag and then using a client side routing solution to work with that (check out [jQuery mobile router](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router)).

Alternatively you can maintain a reference in a js object for each item in your list, keeping the id in the object. The easiest way to do so is  probably by using some sort of javascript mvc type framework like [backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)  where you would have a collection of models representing each item and a view for each item that is hooked up to a particular element in the DOM (in your case an li) and can be wired to respond to events on that element (for example when you click the item that items view responds to its click event and acts accordingly).

**Edit**:

Personally I've been using backbone.js to structure my own code, if your interested in it you should be able to find many tutorials for it. Anyway here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kSMtp/) with the basic idea of using backbone.js to maintain a reference to each item in the list. Of course you can do this also in vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: I have tried looking online for an example similar to this but to no avail. Do you know any website that could help me out ?

Comment: To which approach that I mentioned are you referring to, using routing or having js objects maintaining a reference to the items in the list. I'll try and update my answer a little later with either some links or an example.

Comment: having js objects maintaining reference to the list. The database information will be got through the phonegap API.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I updated my answer with a backbone.js example.